# ngResource: Object has no method query

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

Trying to get ngResource to work, but getting the error:

Object # has no method 'query'

I've tried to keep it as simple as possible and according to the documentations/posts that I can find, this should work. But it doesn't.

Here's my service/factory:

```
var srcServices = angular.module('srcServices', ['ngResource']);

srcServices.factory('Rotation', ['$resource',
  function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/rotations/:id' );
  }]);
```

And here's the controller code triggering the error:

```
var srcControllers = angular.module('srcControllers', ['ngResource']);

srcControllers.controller('RotationListCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'Rotation', function($scope, Rotation, $location) {

  Rotation.query(function(data) {$scope.rotations = data;})

  $scope.edit = function(a) {
    var path = "/rotations/" + a._id.$oid;
    $location.path(path);
  };
}]);
```

Comment: For minification, dependency injections has to be in the same order. `srcControllers.controller('RotationListCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'Rotation', function($scope, $location, Rotation) { } `. Note `$location` is 2nd param and `Rotation` is 3rd.

Comment: This worked even though I'm not using minified js. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var srcControllers = angular.module('srcControllers', ['ngResource', 'srcServices']);
```

You are creating the service as a new angular module. So in order to get access to the service you have to inject it to your controller.

Comment: This didn't seem to make any difference. Same error.